# PHP Instant Messages Update

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am creating a messaging system which have the following parts:

1. A form which send user message and upon submission of the form, PHP inserts the data into a MySQL Table called userMessages.
2. A PHP page which performs a MySQL Query select all from userMessages and displays all the messages.

The problem I'm having is making this messaging system have an *INSTANT* Message Functionality. i.e. I submit data from one form and it instantly appears on the user messages page *WITHOUT* having to manually refresh the page.

I do have temporary solution of refreshing the page every 20 second. But is there a way to update the messages page only at the moment a new message is submitted?

Comment: Yes, Your PHP page has JavaScript which uses Ajax to poll the server for new messages every few seconds, then writes new ones into the DOM.

Comment: node.js would work well in this situation instead of a PHP server

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

Pushing data to a web page is very hard, as Dan Grossman has said you will want to read that wiki article. AJAX polling every few seconds would be a good idea, if you don't mind a rather high server and database load. ama2 is also right - PHP is inherently not the best system for this, and a continuously running application server using, say, node.js, may be a lot more efficient.